# Error running JPA EclipseLink application on IBM Websphere Libery Server

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have been trying to run a `JPA` application which uses `EclipseLink 2.5.1` as a `JPA` provider on IBM Websphere Liberty Server.

I am facing following exception:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWJP0015E: An error occurred in the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the XXXXX persistence unit. The following error occurred: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [XXXXXX] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-28006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: ClassNotFound: [WebSphere_Liberty] specified in [eclipselink.target-server] property.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebSphere_Liberty
```

Since my application contains its own JPA EclipseLink JARS jars, I have only enabled `<feature>jpaContainer-2.1</feature>`

Here is my POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>      
</dependency>
```

Please help me if anyone ever faced this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just in the process of setting this up myself, it appears, you have to define a bell, too (for me, I'm trying hibernate, probably just replace by eclipselink):

in server.xml

```
<feature>jpaContainer-2.1</feature>
<feature>bells-1.0</feature>
.
.
.
<bell libraryRef="hibernate" />
<!-- Include all of the hibernate jars in a shared lib -->
<library id="hibernate">
   <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/hibernate/" includes="*.jar" />
</library>
```

So, you actually have to assemble these jars into the correct folder, and then point your bell to the libs dir.

Comment: Additionally, you can find IBM documentation on how to use the `jpaContainer-2.1` feature here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jpa.html

Comment: I am running a Maven, Web application, so my Maven is already including the jars in `WEB-INF/lib/`. Should I still use `<bell>` feature??

Comment: I'd just do it, as described in the documentation (see @AndyGuibert 's comment); usually I'd agree, though.  BUT how do you start the server? Is it via mvn liberty:run-server?  Then the application path might be completely different, and the classes are probably not picked up from the war file you create with mvn verify.